# Minimagick: undefined method `destroy!' for true:TrueClass auto_orient

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, minimagick

I have an image uploaded that works as expected except when I add an additional process (auto_orient) to the ImageUploader. Codes is as follows:

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  retina!

  if Rails.env.development?
    def store_dir
      "#{Rails.root}/public/uploads/account_#{model.account_id}/product_#{model.product_id}/image_#{model.id}"
    end
  elsif Rails.env.staging? || Rails.env.production?
    def store_dir
      "uploads/account_#{model.account_id}/product_#{model.product_id}/image_#{model.id}"
    end
  end

  def default_url
    "/assets/no_image_500px.png"
  end


  process :auto_orient
  process :resize_and_pad => [500, 500]

  version :thumb_100 do
    process :resize_and_pad => [100, 100]
  end

  version :shopping_cart do
    process :resize_to_fill => [200, 200]
    process :retina_quality => 100
  end

  version :store_page do
    process :resize_to_fill => [336, 336]
    process :retina_quality => 100
  end

  version :product_page do
    process :resize_to_fill => [426, 426]
    process :retina_quality => 100
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg png tiff)
  end

  def auto_orient
    manipulate! do |img|
      img = img.auto_orient
    end
  end

end
```

Auto_orient serves the purpose for a user to upload an image from their mobile phone, the image is auto oriented properly. This current code works for mobile uploaded images, but when I try to upload images from the web app on a desktop, I receive: "undefined method `destroy!' for true:TrueClass".

I've looked at the [documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/image1.html#auto_orient)for minimagick and thought changing auto_orient to auto_orient! but then I'm told minimagick has no method named auto_orient! Why is destroy being called with this method?

Comment: Check whether auto_orient method returns true or object. Mostly method with ! returns true or false. Try replacing manipulate method instead of manipulate!.

Comment: Apparently there is no method auto_orient (without the !) for the carrierwave module. Looking at the documentation, it looks like img is returned.

Comment: @Tommyixi in your question, you write it the opposite way. Which one is right?

Comment: @PatrickOscity I apologize, I meant to say there is no manipulate method, only manipulate!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like manipulate! calls a destroy method on the return of auto_orient (which ends up being a boolean (true)). Hence the error for unable to call delete on a boolean. To fix this, I added the ruby "tap" method to pass in the image to the block and then return the image immediately afterwards:

```
  def auto_orient
    manipulate! do |img|
      img.tap(&:auto_orient)
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps is too late for answer your question but I have another answer, for solve destroy! troubles you must return and img inside manipulate block

```
  def auto_orient
    manipulate! do |img|
      img = img.auto_orient
      img
    end
  end
```